# I am confused using the OpenCV sepfilter2D function's kernelX, and kernelY

Tags: opencv

I don't know how to use sepFilter2D properly. I'm confused using the function parameters such kernelX, kernelY in OpenCV sepFilter2D function.

```
vector<double> filter1; //row vector

sepFilter2D(src, convolvedImg, CV_64FC3, filter1, filter1, Point(-1, -1), 0.0, BORDER_DEFAULT);


//filter1 = [0.00443305      0.0540056       0.242036        0.39905       0.242036        0.0540056       0.00443305]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might be aware, the operation of *convolution* is widely used in image processing. It involves using a 2D filter, usually small in size (e.g. 3x3 or 5x5), and the short explanation is that you overlay the filter to each position, multiply the values in the filter with the values in the image and add everything together. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) page is much more detailed in presenting this operation.

Just to get a sense for this, assuming you have a MxN image and a UxV filter. For each pixel, you have to apply the filter once. Therefore, you have to perform M*N*U*V multiplications and additions.

Some filters have a nice property called separability. You can achieve the same effect of a UxV 2D filter by applying once a horizontal filter of size V and then a vertical filter of size U. Now you have M*N*U + M*N*V = M*N*(U+V) operations, therefore this is more efficient.

The `sepFilter2D` does exactly this: applies a vertical and a horizontal 1D filter. The full function signature is:

`void sepFilter2D(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int ddepth, InputArray kernelX, InputArray kernelY, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), double delta=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT )`

, where `src` is your initial image, the filtered image will be in `dst`, `ddepth` represents the desired type of the destination image, `kernelX` and `kernelY` are the horizontal and vertical 1D kernels I described above, `anchor` represents the kernel origin (default means center), `delta` represents a value that is added to the destination image to offset its brightness and `borderType` represents the method used around borders.

Comment: Can I use vector "filter1" for both kernelX and kernelY in sepFilter2D function?

Comment: No, both `kernelX` and `kernelY` are of the type `cv::Mat`. You can find some ideas about converting a `std::vector` to `cv::Mat` here: https://answers.opencv.org/question/81831/convert-stdvectordouble-to-mat-and-show-the-image/

Comment: When I look at the resulted images were not different while I'm using the vector or Mat. I'm not actually comparing by code. And one more thing that confused me is kernelX size is 1xN (rol x col) and kenelY size is Nx1 (rol x col)?

Comment: @MinThaeHua You are right, there is a constructor of `cv::Mat` that takes a `std::vector`, I missed it previously. What happens when you pass a `std::vector` is that it is implicitly converted to a `cv::Mat`. Yes, kernelX size is 1xN and kenelY size is Nx1.

Comment: I don't know clearly what happens when I pass the std:: vector but the sepFilter2D run smoothly and I think the resulting image are not different too much.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mat data structure to declare kernels. (I'm not sure about vector, I'm not near me PC right now. I'll check later.)

Comment: Do I have to change vector to Mat data structure? The function is working with vector.